# More than 3 mb of data for list of list for 1500 records

Tags: python, django, performance, object, firebug

While sending some list of records to HTML I found my page to be very slow for just 1500  records. On investigation I found there was a huge lot of data being passed for just 1500 records , it was between 3 to 4 mb .
And each row has some 6 values, all are string and two of them are date time objects.

I have looked around and found that dictionaries are heavy and changing dictionary to tuple of data did reduce load in another page.
But in my first page all I am sending is list of thousand records, so it is a list of list.

I tried looking into how much data was being sent for every record through firebug and I found it is more than 1 kb of data per record.

This is a performance issue as my application is a web application all the data is already being compressed.

Can anybody help me with what is going wrong?,are python lists and objects really so heavy?

Please also advise if there is any way to inspect this further.

Comment: And we're supposed to figure out the problem without seeing any code... how? Do us a favor and post some examples - right now this is like going walking to a garage and complaining to the mechanic that your car is slow, and he should fix it immediately.

Comment: :) I'm telling u the problem a a list costs more than a kb , is this common? I Don't think there is anything wrong with the code.

Comment: you just say strings and date objects. How long of a string? A string can be a single char, or it can be a terabyte.

Comment: Strings at max 15 characters long in length :/

Comment: in which format do you send the data? also it might help if you post a sample record and the generated date for it.

Comment: Hmmm I don't have real data but it is something like [ 1223456, 1245361536363,'infooooooooo123',dob(date time), a big link some 20 character long] ... It is something like this

Comment: A record of this type cannot be 1 kB long, but a record + HTTP response headers can. Are you retrieving each record in a separate HTTP request?

Comment: Here is the sample list of real format [385183, 'kbbdyfa  lnapq', 1951-02-17(this is a date obj),'APPLIED THROUGH WEBSITE', 'long link.....html',string max 5 char long,string max 5 char long,  2012-05-15 10:14:00(datetime)]

Comment: @Hristo lliev, that's so true even i don't know how could a list be so heavy ...so what i did is -> rendered a single list to html and checked the size of the page , it turned out to be approx 42 kb+(some constant of js files etc,so we can ignore this constant) then i rendered 2 records to the html page it turned out to be 43+ kb and so on ... after sampling a little more like this ... i confirmed the record is approx 1kb in size

Comment: Can you do a diff on (render with one record) and (render with two records)? This should precisely show you the page-consequences of adding one record.

Comment: @HughBothwell wow that's a good advise .. i never thought of it , why didnt u put this a reply itself, it will be useful for ppl too. I will check this out but can u also advise on how does it matter if there is js working on every record of if i have events like on click for every record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show you how much memory is used:

```
import sys

a = ["abcdef", "ghijklmnop"]
sys.getsizeof(a)    # => 44 (size of list a in bytes)
```

When you talk about "sending the list to HTML", are you talking about rendering the page in Python, or are you sending it as JSON? Are you sending only the minimum data needed, or are you sending "everything" and then filtering?

.

**Edit:** Good point. How about the following:

```
import sys
import datetime

def show_mem(data, indent="    ", depth=0):
    "Recursively show the memory usage of a data structure"
    mysize = sys.getsizeof(data)
    if isinstance(data, (list,tuple,dict)):
        childsize = 0
        print("{}{} bytes: [".format(indent*depth, mysize))
        for d in data:
            childsize += show_mem(d, indent, depth+1)
        print("{}]  (total: {} bytes)".format(indent*depth, mysize+childsize))
        return mysize+childsize
    else:
        print("{}{} bytes: {}".format(indent*depth, mysize, repr(data)))
        return mysize

show_mem([1223456, 1245361536363, 'infooooooooo123', datetime.date(1975,7,21), "http://www.somesite.org/the/path/page.htm"])
```

which returns

```
56 bytes: [
    12 bytes: 1223456
    18 bytes: 1245361536363L
    36 bytes: 'infooooooooo123'
    20 bytes: datetime.date(1975, 7, 21)
    62 bytes: 'http://www.somesite.org/the/path/page.htm'
]  (total: 204 bytes)
```

.

**Edit #2:** You should run diff on (page rendered with one record) versus (page rendered with two records); this should precisely show you the page-consequences of adding one record. It is possible that your HTML has lots of hidden attributes or inline Javascript which is inflating its size.

ie, on the Linux command line:

```
diff -b saved_one_record.html saved_two_records.html
```

should return something like

```
61a66
><tr class="rowA">
    <td class="_1"><a href="#row=1223456" alt="Show details">1223456</a></td>
    <td class="_2"><span style="">1245361536363</span></td>
    <td class="_3"><a href="http://www.somesite.org/the/path/page.htm"><b>infooooooooo123</b></a></td>
    <td class="_4">July 21 1975</td>
</tr>
```

as the final rendered per-row HTML from your Django template. In this example, 204 bytes of data-structure has become 306 bytes of HTML-file. Per your tests, you should see something over a thousand characters. If you post your diff results, maybe we can give you some ideas for making it more compact.

Comment: Thanks for the comment ...I'm rendering to HTML via django , I'm sending only required fields in a list. But when we do what you suggested we get the size of only the list container na, what about the inner data like the strings and date objects. We can't measure them like this right ?

Comment: On console even i am getting a small number but when it is rendered on the html page it has 1kb of size, i wonder what is happening and i don't know what to look and where. Any suggestions? to check the size of every record what i did is -> rendered a single list to html and checked the size of the whole page , it turned out to be approx 42 kb+(some constant of js files etc,so we can ignore this constant) then i rendered 2 records to the html page it turned out to be 43+ kb and so after sampling a little more like this ... i confirmed the record is approx 1kb in size

Comment: @turtle s: so what does "one record" look like when rendered into HTML? Are you adding a pile of javascript onmouseover attributes or something?

Comment: thanks for that amazing view into the problem , i could have never thought of such things could also matter, could u explain the concept behind ur point as a reply? it will be very helpful as i don't know the concept behind ur point yet

Comment: wow @Hugh Bothwell, that was a really good advise I'll do as you suggested and I'll investigate more in this direction and I'll update you, then maybe we'll understand the issue a little more.